# flask - How to query/iterate over 2 seperate bootstrap tables

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2

1. I have 2 table in postgres table A and B that (they are exactly the same in terms of column names and number of columns)
2. I have 2 table in bootstrap
3. I want to query from postgres table A to table A of (bootstrap)
4. I want to query from postgres table B to table B of (bootstrap)

Lets say I want to accomplish this using python list

```
aList = ['A', 'B']

for network in aList:
    db.session.execute("SELECT * from booTable"+network+" ")
```

So in python/jinja How to make the above query that if network A, display in table A in index.html and if network B,  put it in table B.

Currently what I have is:

```
@app.route('/')
def Index():
    tableA = db.session.execute("SELECT * from booTableA").fetchall()
    tableB = db.session.execute("SELECT * from booTableB").fetchall()

    return render_template("index.html", tableA=tableA, tableB=tableB)
```

and in index.html this is what I have:

```
<table class="table">
 {% for a in tableA %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{a.name}}</td>
      <td>{{a.age}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
{% for b in tableB%}
  <tr>
    <td>{{b.name}}</td>
    <td>{{b.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It would be great to have one execute query for multiple table to accomplish above task because if I have multiple network/table then I can add "+network+" at the end instead of executing multiple select query for evey network/table . Any help with achieving the above issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like hidden assumptions. Please fill in "It would be great (because ...)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
aList = ['A', 'B']
results = OrderedDict()

for network in aList:
    ret_ = db.session.execute("SELECT * from booTable"+network+" ")
    results[network] = ret_
```

Then in your jinja:

```
{% for key, values in results.items() %}
    <table class="table">
        {% for v in values %}

        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

This will allow you to build your table based on the network key and then loop through the items.

*Disclaimer: code written off the top of my head, may not work if you copy and paste. It's up to you to put exception handling and checks*

Comment: Thank you very much @CodeLikeBeaker. Your above approach solved my issue. Sorry couldn't upvote since I don't have enough reputation.